# Grub2 booting MacOSx ISO

Tags: boot, grub2

I need your help!

I have Ubuntu installed and a chainload with the Windows Boot Manager!

And now I read about grub2 that it is possible to boot an ISO directly with grub2.
For Windows I needed the chainload with grub and Windows Boot Manager. Do I need any kind of it for MacOSx?
And the next question is, how do I manage this? Which commands do I need.

I was already looking up on the internet for this problem, but I wasn't able to find anything about it. Everyone's talking about the Usage of grub2 on a Mac, but that's not the thing I want to do.

Thanks and greetings to all